# Multi-GPU for peer to peer

Tags: cuda, fortran, multi-gpu

I have some difficulties setting 2 GPUs for peer to peer communication.
I am using Cuda 4.0 and programming with fortran. PGI compiler

I wrote a program which confirm I have 4 GPUs available on my node.

I decided to use two of them but having  the following error: 
**0: DEALLOCATE: invalid device pointer**.

```
subroutine  directTransfer()

        use cudafor
        implicit none

        integer, parameter :: N = 4*1024*1024
        real, pinned, allocatable :: a(:), b(:)
        real, device, allocatable :: a_d(:), b_d(:)


        !these hold free and total memory before and after
        !allocation, used to verify  allocation happening on proper devices

        integer (int_ptr_kind()),allocatable ::
     &   freeBefore(:), totalBefore(:),
     &   freeAfter(:), totalAfter(:)

        integer :: istat, nDevices, i, accessPeer, timingDev
        type(cudaDeviceProp)::prop
        type(cudaEvent)::startEvent,stopEvent
        real :: time

        !allocate host arrays
        allocate(a(N), b(N))
        allocate(freeBefore(0:nDevices -1),
     &      totalBefore(0:nDevices -1))
        allocate(freeAfter(0:nDevices -1),
     &      totalAfter(0:nDevices -1))
        write(*,*) 'Start!'
        !get devices ionfo (including total and free memory)
        !before allocation
        istat = cudaGetDeviceCount(nDevices)
        if(nDevices < 2) then
            write(*,*) 'Need at least two CUDA capable devices'
            stop
        end if

          write(*,"('Number of CUDA-capable devices: ',
     &       i0, /)"),nDevices

        do i = 0, nDevices - 1
            istat = cudaGetDeviceProperties(prop, i)
            istat = cudaSetDevice(i)
            istat = cudaMemGetInfo(freeBefore(i), totalBefore(i))
        end do

       !!!Here is the trouble zone!!!!
        istat = cudaSetDevice(0)
        allocate(a_d(N))
        istat = cudaSetDevice(1)
        allocate(b_d(N))


       deallocate(freeBefore, totalBefore,freeAfter,totalAfter)
       deallocate(a,b,a_d,b_d)
       end subroutine  directTransfer
```

With the following I have no error:

```
istat = cudaSetDevice(0)
allocate(a_d(N))
!istat = cudaSetDevice(1)
!allocate(b_d(N))
```

With this, also no error:

```
!istat = cudaSetDevice(0)
!allocate(a_d(N))
istat = cudaSetDevice(1)
allocate(b_d(N))
```

But this return error

```
istat = cudaSetDevice(0)
allocate(a_d(N))
istat = cudaSetDevice(1)
allocate(b_d(N))
```

So it seems I cannot set 2GPUs to start my program. 
Could you help me understand why it is not possible to set 2GPUs and a hint to solve this?

Comment: I am not a cuda fortran user, but I think that, before deallocating, you should first set the device the corresponding variable was alocated on.

Comment: In essence, I think you cannot deallocate a_d and b_d with the same command, but a cuda set device should appear in between.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you JackOLantern!!

It was the trick. 
I changed the code as following and it works perfectly

```
!clean up      
deallocate(freeBefore, totalBefore,freeAfter,totalAfter)
istat = cudaSetDevice(0)
deallocate(a_d)
istat = cudaSetDevice(1)
deallocate(b_d)
deallocate(a,b)
```

This was my problem answer. Hope it will help others.